# Nasty algebra substitution problem

Tags: substitution

From [this](https://sirrah.troja.mff.cuni.cz/~mira/mp/phdth/yarkovsky_effect_phdth_broz.pdf) PhD dissertation, page 29:

Reduce the formula 
$$
    T(0, t) = T_{eq} + \frac{(1 − A)}{(1+i)\sqrt{\pi fKC\rho} + 4\epsilon\sigma T^{4}_{eq}}\epsilon_{1}e^{i2\pi ft}
$$

down to 
$$
    T(0, t) = T_{eq} + \frac{(1 − A)}{4\epsilon\sigma T^{3}_{eq}} \frac{1}{1+2\Theta +2\Theta^{2}}\epsilon_{1}e^{i(2\pi ft + \phi_{th})}
$$

using the fact that
$$
\Theta = \frac{\sqrt{\pi fKC\rho}}{4\pi\epsilon\sigma T^{3}_{eq}}
$$
and
$$
\tan{\phi_{th}} = -\frac{\Theta}{1 + \Theta}
$$

I can't for the life of me get this. I suspect it is a lot of work, some pointers would be appreciated.

EDIT:
So I think this may be incorrect. In my opinion 
$$
\Theta = \frac{\sqrt{\pi fKC\rho}}{4\epsilon\sigma T^{4}_{eq}}
$$
With this it can be easily shown that 
$$
    T(0, t) = T_{eq} + \frac{(1 − A)}{4\epsilon\sigma T^{4}_{eq}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\Theta +2\Theta^{2}}}\epsilon_{1}e^{i(2\pi ft - \phi_{th})}
$$
which is somewhat different, but also makes more sense to me from a physics perspective (minus phase factor and quadratic square rooted). Also how he went from T^4 to T^3 is really beyond me (it's thermal radiation so should really radiate according to T^4 imo).

Comment: Shorn of the clutter, you are aiming to show that
$$\frac1{(1+i)\Theta+\sqrt\pi}=\frac{\exp(-i\arctan(\Theta/(1+\Theta)))}
{1+2\Theta+2\Theta^2}$$
or at least something similar (I'm not sure that is quite right). My tip is to
work on $\exp(-i\arctan(\Theta/(1+\Theta)))$.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice, just working on the denominator as that's all that changes, but I'm thinking there may be an error here in his working. Posted and edit.